# Changing attributes soap:body

Tags: perl, soaplite

I'm using perl, SOAP::Lite. Does anyone know how to change the tag attributes of soap:body? What I really need is the way to add an ID attribute to the soap:Body tag in SOAP::Lite perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to override the serializer as described [here](http://cookbook.soaplite.com/#creating%20custom%20serializer)